# Vue.js - using v-on:click and v-link together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm developing a Vue.js app and I'm trying to make a log in system using multiple components.

on my App.vue component (which is the "primary" component and has the nav-bar) there is this button:

```
<a class="nav-item" v-link="'login'" v-if="!user.authenticated">Login</a>

...

import auth from '../auth'

export default {
 data(){
  return{
   user = auth.user
  } 
 }
}
```

In one other file (/auth/index.js) I define the "auth" methods as such:

```
...
  user: {
    authenticated: false
  },

  login(email, password) {
    axios.post(LOGIN_URL, {
      email,
      password
    }).then((response) => {
      this.user.authenticated = true;
      this.user = response.data;
      router.go('/home');
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And then I have another component name Login.vue that handles the view for the login template and calls the "auth.login" method with the required params.

The thing is that I want to update the user from App.vue with the value from auth.user AFTER he logs in. How should I do that? Do I have to manage the v-on:click and v-link priorities and come up with a new method?

EDIT:

I'm also trying to use the beforeRouteEnter method by I am not being successful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution adding this:

```
watch: {
  $route () {
    this.user = auth.user
  }
},
```

Following the documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html)